# Having trouble creating error statements when creating function

Tags: r

I am creating a function in R for calculating compound interest using the equation - F=P\left(1+\frac{i}{100t}\right)^{ty}.

I need to create error messages if any of P, i, t, or y arguments are not numeric or negative, and an error if i is out of the range 0-100.

When I try to run the code i get the error message:
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"    stop("Argument 'P','i','t' and 'y' must be numeric")
    if(P,"
and am unsure how to fix it or what I have done wrong. The code so far is:

```
compound <- function(P,i,t=12,y,plotit=FALSE,...){

   # 1. Check arguments and throw errors here using 'if' statements
  if(!is.numeric(P,i,t,y)){
    stop("Argument 'P','i','t' and 'y' must be numeric")
    if(P,i,t,y<0){
      stop("Argument 'P','i','t' and 'y' must be non-negative")
      if(i<0||i>100){
        stop("'i' must be within the range 0-100 percent")
      }
    }
  }

  if(plotit==TRUE){
    # 2. Do plot if necessary here according to 'plotit' argument
    y <- floor(y)
    f <- P*((1+(i/100*t))^t*y)
  for(i in length(y)){
    plot(f, type = 's')
   } 
  }
  else {
  final.result <- f
  # Calculate final result here
  return(final.result)
  }
}
```

Any help on how to improve the code would be great!

Comment: `if(!(is.numeric(P) && is.numeric(i) && is.numeric(t) && is.numeric(y)))` and `if(P < 0 || i < 0 || t < 0 || y < 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing four arguments to `is.numeric(P,i,t,y)`. It can take only one.

```r
if(!all(sapply(list(P,i,t,y), is.numeric)))
```

That will check if all arguments are numeric.

A similar problem occurs with `if(P,i,t,y<0)`, so use:

```r
if(!all(sapply(list(P,i,t,y), function(x) x >= 0)))
```

Additionally, you have nested these if statements, which means the second and the third will not be evaluated. Move them out of your first if statement.